# FTP connection problem (Could not retrieve Directory Listing)

Tags: ftp

Fiends I have installed an Ubuntu Server and tried to connect with a FTP client. The connection established but generated the following error:

227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,97,206,30).
Estado: El servidor envió una respuesta pasiva con una dirección no enrutable. Usando en su lugar la dirección del servidor.
Comando:    MLSD
Error:  Conexión superó el tiempo de espera
Error:  Error al recuperar el listado del directorio

What can I do to solve this. Many Thanks for any Help.

**[Translated Error]**

`Error: Could not retrieve directory listing`
`Address for passive mode is not routable`

Answer (score 0):

I've had very good results in mixed network environments (window-ubuntu) with this method:

1) Press alt+F2 >> type gksu gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf

2) Look for this line: hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

3) Add "wins" so it looks like this: hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns mdns4

4) Install the "winbind" package: sudo apt-get install winbind (or via software center or synaptic)

5) Reboot or restart your network